# Resize UIImageView to fit portrait image when image is downloaded in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, image-resizing, dynamic-resizing

So in my TableViewCell, I have a label, below the label, I have an imageview with size (320*320), below the imageview I have another UIView with some stuff in it. My tableview is using automatic row height and I am downloading image from URL and loaded onto the imageview. I'm also using sdwebimage cache to cache the image after the image is downloaded.

My problem now is for landscape images (image width < image height), I'm fine with using AspectFit and image is fit nicely in the imageview. However, for portrait images (image width > image height), the image will not fill the whole height of the imageview (since i'm using aspectfit) and it will leave white spaces between top and bottom label and UIView.

I tried to resize the imageview height to shrink it to the height of the image. What I did is in the completion block of downloading image method, I check if the image width is larger, then I change the imageview to the new imageview with new resized height, but I can't make it work with autolayout. When the image show up first, it imageview seems to have resized, but then when I scroll down and scroll backup, it's no longer working.

Below is the code I used in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] queryDiskCacheForKey:cacheKey done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    if (image != nil) {
        float maxWidth = self.productImageView.frame.size.width;
        float maxHeight = self.productImageView.frame.size.height;
        float actualWidth = image.size.width;
        float actualHeight = image.size.height;
        float imageRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;

        if (actualWidth > actualHeight) {
            imageRatio = maxWidth/actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imageRatio * actualHeight;

            if (actualHeight < maxHeight) {
                self.productImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.productImageView.frame.origin.x, self.productImageView.frame.origin.y, maxWidth, actualHeight);
            }
        }

        self.productImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        self.productImageView.image = image;
        self.productImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    } else {
        // download image from remote server
        [self downloadProductImage:sellPost.productImageURL withCacheKey:cacheKey];
    }
}];
```